# download ipad simulator 5.0 in Xcode 4.5.1

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

Please let me know how to get the ipad simulator 5.0 / 5.1. We are using xcode 4.5 and the default simulator is 6.0. We need to test it in ipad 5.0 also. Googling also doesnot seem to provide appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode - Preferences - Downloads - Components - iOS 5.0/5.1 Simulator.

UPDATE: I found this post, [Xcode 4.5 and iOS 5.1 Simulator](http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator) sounds like there is something error with Xcode 4.5 and iOS 5.1 simulator. Try to upgrade to Xcode 4.5.2.

Comment: In components no options like IOS 5.0/5.1 seems available.

Comment: @user1531912 Checkout the link in my edited answer. Maybe you can try Xcode 4.5.2 first.